# Can we override the intersection method of Guava to compare objects?

Tags: java, set, guava

I have tried to compare to sets of type String using the Sets.intersection method() in Guava. It works fine. I want to know what method should I implement to compare two objects? I have overridden the compareTo() method but the Sets.intersection treat similar objects as different. Can you advice please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Given the implementation of `Sets.intersection()`:

```
public static <E> SetView<E> intersection(final Set<E> set1, final Set<?> set2) {
    //...
    return new SetView<E>() {
      //...
      @Override public boolean contains(Object object) {
        return set1.contains(object) && set2.contains(object);
      }
      @Override public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> collection) {
        return set1.containsAll(collection)
            && set2.containsAll(collection);
      }
    };
  }
```

I'd say you have to implement whatever methods are needed to make `contains()` and `containsAll()` work for the `Set`s you pass in, because all the work is delegated to the `Set`s you pass in.

So for `HashSet`s that would be `equals()` and `hashCode()`, and for `TreeSet`s that would be `compareTo()` if you implement `Comparable` or `compare()` if you use a `Comparator` (probably want to still override `equals()` and `hashCode()` to keep things consistent outside the `Map` too).

Comment: `compareTo()`/`compare()` should be all that a `TreeSet` uses to determine equality. That said, `compareTo()` _should_ (but is not strictly required to) be consistent with `equals`, such that if two elements compare as `0` they should always be equal according to `equals()`. This implies implementing `hashCode()` correctly as well.

Comment: @ColinD Updated my answer to take that into account. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You just have to read the definition of [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Set.html):

> More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element.

Implement `hashCode()` and `equals()`.